# Rust: move TcpStream as mutble to multi thread

Tags: rust

want to bind the Standard IO stream to TCP stream
Working ex:

```
fn main() {
    let mut stream =TcpStream::connect("localhost:1912").unwrap();
    let stdin = io::stdin();

    for command in stdin.lock().lines()  {
        {
          let mut cmd = command.unwrap();
          cmd = cmd.add("\n");
          _ = stream.write(cmd.as_bytes()).unwrap();
        }

        {
          let mut resp_data = [0 as u8; 250];
          _ = stream.read(&mut resp_data).unwrap();        
          let text = from_utf8(&resp_data).unwrap();
          print!("{}", text);
        }
    }

}
```

Same I want to do in multi-thread like :
not working:

```
fn main() {
    let stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(TcpStream::connect("localhost:1912").unwrap()));
    
    let str_clone = stream.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {

        let mut stout = io::stdout();
        let mut str = str_clone.lock().unwrap();
        _ = io::copy(&mut *str, &mut stout);

    });

    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut str = stream.lock().unwrap();
    _ = io::copy(&mut stdin, &mut *str);
}
```

I know that one thread is holding a lock so I am not able to access this on another thread.
I am new to Rust so need to know that best way to do this

Ex:
This same I was able to do in GoLang like this

```
func main() {
    c, _ := net.Dial("tcp", ":1912")
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, c)
    io.Copy(c, os.Stdin)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [TcpStream::try_clone](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.try_clone) to get a second copy of the stream.

> Creates a new independently owned handle to the underlying socket.
>
> The returned `TcpStream` is a reference to the same stream that this object references. Both handles will read and write the same stream of data, and options set on one stream will be propagated to the other stream.

Then, you don't need `Arc` or `Mutex` - you can move the second copy into the spawned thread.

```rust
use std::io;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:1912").unwrap();
    let mut stream2 = stream.try_clone().expect("could not clone the stream");

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut stout = io::stdout();
        io::copy(&mut stream2, &mut stout).expect("error while reading from the stream");
    });

    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    io::copy(&mut stdin, &mut stream).expect("error while writing to the stream");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, in general how to decide when to use clone or Arc? How to decide

Comment: `TcpStream` is an outlier, as cloning it only clones the Rust structure which is a wrapper on the OS socket primitive - behind the scenes, both copies of `TcpStream` still operate on the same socket. In most other cases, cloning will actually make a deep copy, and if you want to share a structure, you'll want something like `Arc` & `Mutex`. E.g. cloning a `Vec` will make a separate, unrelated vector, and changes to one will not be reflected in the other.